# How to make Drag and Drop list make copy instead of moving the list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have two different divs, One is full with list item and another is blank. I can Drag the list items from left to right. I am using **[jQuery Sortable](http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/)** Bootstrap plugin.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gtvhtpt5/3/)**

With this plugin if I drag One list from left to right List it self goes(moves) on the right side  But my requirement is if I drag and Drop a **COPY** of list will goes on the right side. It should not move.

So if I say from my example: I Drag Item 5 to right side and a Copy of Item 5 will create and Left side remain as same.

I am not sure if it can be done with jQuery UI plugin but I don't want to use UI because I it is a very big file to have and I am already have so many. So any help about this or any other plugin will really help me because I am stuck here all day
[Sorry for Bad English]

**JS**

```
var adjustment

$("ol.simple_with_animation").sortable({
  group: 'simple_with_animation',
  pullPlaceholder: false,
  // animation on drop
  onDrop: function  (item, targetContainer, _super) {
    var clonedItem = $('<li/>').css({height: 0})
    item.before(clonedItem)
    clonedItem.animate({'height': item.height()})

    item.animate(clonedItem.position(), function  () {
      clonedItem.detach()
      _super(item)
    })
  },

  // set item relative to cursor position
  onDragStart: function ($item, container, _super) {
    var offset = $item.offset(),
    pointer = container.rootGroup.pointer

    adjustment = {
      left: pointer.left - offset.left,
      top: pointer.top - offset.top
    }

    _super($item, container)
  },
  onDrag: function ($item, position) {
    $item.css({
      left: position.left - adjustment.left,
      top: position.top - adjustment.top
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrapped the first element in another div, and also gave the gray box an id. I then clone the gray box using jQuery's `.clone(true, true)` on dragStart. The `true, true` parameters are important to clone the event listeners bound to the object. The Sortable library provides `afterMove` on which I remove the original gray div and append its clone.

```
afterMove: function ($placeholder, container, $closestItemOrContainer) {
  b.remove();
  a.appendTo(append);
  $("ol.simple_with_animation").sortable("destroy");
  e();
},
```

I call `.sortable("destroy")` on the objects so that their state can be refreshed on the recursive execution of the `e()` function.

Note that I've put the whole thing in a recursive function, `e()`, but you could implement this differently, using another event listener.

[Here's the JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/5yn2vgup/)